# Did Maul find a way to prevent death using the dark side of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, sith, the-clone-wars, darth-maul

By and large, the Sith had always sought to overcome death itself, believing the dark side to hold the ultimate secret of immortality. Darth Vader was not the first Sith Lord who wished to stop death, though he may possibly be the only one who wanted to stop the death of a loved one rather than himself.

However, only one Sith, at least from my point of view, has actually survived what should have been an inevitable death: Darth Maul. He (formerly Darth, now just Maul) was sliced into two halves by Obi-Wan. Normally, even immediate medical attention could not guarantee survival. It was his pure hatred of Kenobi and desire for vengeance that fuelled the dark side into keeping him alive, until Savage Oppress found him over a decade later and brought him to Mother Talzin, who used dark side sorcery to bring him back to a state of sanity and consciousness.

Has Darth Maul subconsciously and unknowingly found a way to prevent death to himself using the dark side? Is this, perhaps, the answer the Sith had been looking for all along?

Comment: The answers on the duplicate question discuss Maul's survival (and the use of the Dark Side of the Force to accomplish this) in great detail.